# scss interpolation help for passing the values

Tags: css, sass, scss-lint, scss-mixins

I need to create dynamic classes for which I am creating a scss code to create the classes for all the possible values. Below is my code:-

```
$colors: (
    "black": "0,0,0",
    "white": "255,255,255",
    "red" : "255,0,0"
);


$opacity:9;
@for $i from 0 through $opacity {
  $j:$i/10;
  @each $color, $rgb in $colors {
    $rgba: "#{$rgb},#{$j}";
    .background-#{$color}-#{$i} {
      background: #{$rgba};
    }
  }
}
```

I want it to give out put as :-

```
.background-black-0 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.background-white-0 {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}

.background-red-0 {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0);
}

.background-black-1 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.background-white-1 {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.background-red-1 {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

struggling with the interpolation for rgba(). Otherwise its getting the exact values I want. If you check my code in https://www.sassmeister.com/ you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use directly your colors as rgb color in your map and then add opacity in your `@for` loop:

```
$colors: (
    "black": rgb(0,0,0),
    "white": rgb(255,255,255),
    "red": rgb(255,0,0)
);


$opacity:9;

@for $i from 0 through $opacity {
  $j:$i/10;
  @each $color, $rgb in $colors {
    .background-#{$color}-#{$i} {
      background: rgba($rgb, $j);
    }
  }
}
```